# How to filter an object array using another array to define which objects to filter out

Tags: objective-c, sql, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

In xcode, I have a database that I request from an online sql database and this can be stored into an array or NSDictionary or other type. Separately, an array of numbers is generated in the app which correspond to one of the columns of the database.

I want to filter the database to only show objects involved with generated array. Once filtered, I want to list the results in a string. The database from the online server can be stored in an NSArray or an NSDictionary if need be, and probably other formats that I don't know about.

The procedure would look something like this:

Database array:          Generated Array:       Resultant array after filtering the database:

```
ID    |    Name          ID                        FilteredNames
      |
1A    |   Hannah         1A                          Hannah
2A    |   John           1B                          Steve
3A    |   Peter          2B                          Zara
1B    |   Steve
2B    |   Zara
3B    |   Kyle
```

The the resultant array "FilteredNames" converted to a String list as follows:

```
NamesString = @"Hannah, Steve, Zara"
```

I then plan to pass the NamesString to a label as follows:

```
label.text=NamesString;
```

and so the label in the view just shows :

```
                                Hannah, Steve, Zara
```

I pretty much need help for this entire procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Following Martin's comment, changed the predicate format to a much more appropriate one.

```
- (NSArray *)filterObjects:(NSArray *)objects withNames:(NSArray *)names {
  return [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", names]];
}

// given that the 'objects' array is what you get from server
  NSArray *objects = @[
                       @{@"id" : @"1A", @"name" : @"Hannah"},
                       @{@"id" : @"2A", @"name" : @"John"},
                       @{@"id" : @"3A", @"name" : @"Peter"},
                       @{@"id" : @"1B", @"name" : @"Steve"},
                       @{@"id" : @"2B", @"name" : @"Zara"},
                       @{@"id" : @"3B", @"name" : @"Kyle"}
                       ];

  NSArray *filteredObjects = [self filterObjects:objects withNames:@[@"Hannah", @"John", @"Zara"]];
  NSLog(@"filteredObjects: %@", filteredObjects); // prints them out as dictionaries

  NSString *unitedNames = [[filteredObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.name"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
  NSLog(@"unitedNames: %@", unitedNames); // comma separated array of names
```

Comment: I thank you Sir, after going through i managed to get it working as you suggested, Many thanks.

Comment: I would not recommend to use string formatting functions to create a complex predicate. This breaks immediately if any of the search strings contains the character `'`. Actually there is a much simpler solution here, using `@"name IN %@", names`. In more complex cases, you can `NSCompoundPredicate` to create AND/OR combinations.

Comment: Works just as well and is indeed far less complicated. Thanks so much for your help. Ill look into NSCompundPredicate but presumably thats not needed in this case right?